# How to trouble Android signal 11 (SIGSEGV)

Tags: android

I am getting signal 11 (SIGSEGV) fatal error in my Android app, which is not NDK app. By looking through the logcat file, I have almost no clue how to trace down this error. The error occurs (and my app crashes) when a push notification is opened. Is there a better way to debug this problem?

Here is my logcat content:

```html
F/libc    ( 6556): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 6662 (IntentService[E)
D/dalvikvm( 6651): GC_CONCURRENT freed 818K, 22% free 4881K/6232K, paused 1ms+3ms, total 5ms
D/dalvikvm( 6651): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 897K, 26% free 4845K/6504K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
D/dalvikvm( 6651): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 881K, 26% free 4838K/6504K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
I/DEBUG   ( 1885): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   ( 1885): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/santos10wifiue/santos10wifi:4.4.2/KOT49H/P5210UEU0CNK1:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   ( 1885): Revision: '0'
I/DEBUG   ( 1885): pid: 6556, tid: 6662, name: IntentService[E  >>> com.nellymoser.android.vosl <<<
I/DEBUG   ( 1885): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
I/MultiDex( 6651): VM with version 1.6.0 does not have multidex support
I/MultiDex( 6651): install
I/MultiDex( 6651): MultiDexExtractor.load(/data/app/com.tripadvisor.tripadvisor-4.apk, false)
I/MultiDex( 6651): loading existing secondary dex files
I/MultiDex( 6651): load found 1 secondary dex files
I/MultiDex( 6651): install done
W/ActivityManager( 2340): Permission Denial: getCurrentUser() from pid=6651, uid=10103 requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
D/dalvikvm( 6651): GC_CONCURRENT freed 763K, 24% free 4997K/6504K, paused 4ms+2ms, total 8ms
D/dalvikvm( 6651): GC_CONCURRENT freed 778K, 22% free 5133K/6504K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 6ms
D/dalvikvm( 6651): GC_CONCURRENT freed 857K, 22% free 5191K/6640K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 7ms
I/SurfaceFlinger( 1888): Device Built-in Screen -> ls 0 
D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController( 2539): refreshSignalCluster - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController( 2539): refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false
D/STATUSBAR-IconMerger( 2539): checkOverflow(588), More:false, Req:false Child:3
E/SELinux ( 6671): [DEBUG] seapp_context_lookup: seinfoCategory = default
D/dalvikvm( 6671): Process 6671 nice name: com.sec.android.app.samsungapps.una2
D/dalvikvm( 6671): Extra Options: not specified
I/SensorManagerA( 2680): getReportingMode :: sensor.mType = 1
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     eax ffffffff  ebx 00000000  ecx 00000008  edx 6735ada0
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     esi 00000000  edi 00000008
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000000  xss 0000007b
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     eip 417674e0  ebp 67943768  esp 67943720  flags 00210246
I/SurfaceFlinger( 1888): Device Built-in Screen -> ls 0 
I/DEBUG   ( 1885): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1885): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     #00  pc 0003a4e0  /system/lib/libssl.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     #01  pc 0000849a  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     #02  pc 00047042  /system/lib/libssl.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     #03  pc 000201a3  /system/lib/libssl.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     #04  pc 0001ec57  /system/lib/libssl.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     #05  pc 000392bd  /system/lib/libssl.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     #06  pc 00015c39  /system/lib/libssl.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     #07  pc 0003bc52  /system/lib/libssl.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     #08  pc 00016b55  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     #09  pc 00083335  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     #10  pc 00001c6f  <unknown>
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     #11  pc 000e06dc  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     #12  pc 00237c79  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     #13  pc 0000ea53  <unknown>
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     #14  pc 00098c80  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     #15  pc 000948c1  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     #16  pc 001144ae  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     #17  pc 00114877  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     #18  pc 000f24b2  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     #19  pc 0001c092  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     #20  pc 0004b805  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     #21  pc 000f20ff  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     #22  pc ffffffff  <unknown>
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     #23  pc 000048df  <unknown>
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     #24  pc 000030cd  <unknown>
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     #25  pc 0000740f  <unknown>
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     #26  pc 000b4dff  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     #27  pc 00012f2f  /system/lib/libutils.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     #28  pc 000b952f  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     #29  pc 000b956f  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     #30  pc ffffffff  <unknown>
I/DEBUG   ( 1885): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1885): stack:
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          679436e0  401217e0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          679436e4  5f477486  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          679436e8  413a8e74  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          679436ec  412c1b37  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          679436f0  00000006  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          679436f4  00000002  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          679436f8  4135e8e2  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          679436fc  000001ff  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          67943700  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          67943704  40039000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          67943708  67943738  [stack:6662]
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          6794370c  412fe102  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          67943710  68fa4480  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          67943714  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          67943718  4127f509  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          6794371c  41767478  /system/lib/libssl.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     #00  67943720  67dbe4b0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          67943724  67dbe4a8  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          67943728  67943798  [stack:6662]
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          6794372c  41766818  /system/lib/libssl.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          67943730  68fdb01d  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          67943734  41785a58  /system/lib/libssl.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          67943738  68fdb01d  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          6794373c  00000001  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          67943740  41785a58  /system/lib/libssl.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          67943744  68fdb01e  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          67943748  00000008  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          6794374c  412bce94  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          67943750  6735af90  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          67943754  40039000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          67943758  00000190  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          6794375c  6735ada0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          ........  ........
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     #01  67943770  679437f8  [stack:6662]
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          67943774  679437f7  [stack:6662]
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          67943778  68fdb01d  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          6794377c  00000012  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          67943780  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          67943784  ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          67943788  67dbe4e8  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          6794378c  67dbe4b0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          67943790  67dbe4b0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          67943794  413a8e74  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          67943798  679437c8  [stack:6662]
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          6794379c  41785a58  /system/lib/libssl.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          679437a0  6735ada0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          679437a4  00000012  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          679437a8  67943818  [stack:6662]
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          679437ac  41774043  /system/lib/libssl.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):     #02  679437b0  6735ada0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          679437b4  679437f8  [stack:6662]
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          679437b8  679437f7  [stack:6662]
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          679437bc  68fdb01d  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          679437c0  00000012  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          679437c4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          679437c8  67943818  [stack:6662]
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          679437cc  41752d80  /system/lib/libssl.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          679437d0  00000001  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          679437d4  00000001  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          679437d8  68fdb02f  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          679437dc  68fdb02b  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          679437e0  68fdb019  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          679437e4  68fdb01d  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          679437e8  68fdb02f  
I/DEBUG   ( 1885):          679437ec  00000012
```

**UPDATE:** 
Another instance of the logcat file when it crashed again:

```html
W/GCM-DMM ( 2758): broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=com.nellymoser.android.vosl (has extras) }
F/libc    (15411): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 15518 (IntentService[E)
I/DEBUG   ( 1886): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   ( 1886): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/santos10wifiue/santos10wifi:4.4.2/KOT49H/P5210UEU0CNK1:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   ( 1886): Revision: '0'
I/DEBUG   ( 1886): pid: 15411, tid: 15518, name: IntentService[E  >>> com.nellymoser.android.vosl <<<
I/DEBUG   ( 1886): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController( 2542): refreshSignalCluster - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController( 2542): refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false
D/STATUSBAR-IconMerger( 2542): checkOverflow(588), More:false, Req:false Child:4
D/ConnectivityService( 2344): handleInetConditionHoldEnd: net=1, condition=100, published condition=100
D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController( 2542): onReceive() - CONNECTIVITY_ACTION, INET_CONDITION_ACTION
I/SurfaceFlinger( 1888): Device Built-in Screen -> ls 0 
D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController( 2542): getUpdateDataNetType() - mDataNetType:0
D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController( 2542): updateDataNetType()
D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController( 2542): NoService, mRoamingIconId = 0
D/SensorService( 2344):   -0.1 -0.1 10.0
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     eax ffffffff  ebx 00000000  ecx 00000008  edx 686940c0
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     esi 00000000  edi 00000008
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000000  xss 0000007b
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     eip 417674e0  ebp 6896d768  esp 6896d720  flags 00210246
I/DEBUG   ( 1886): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1886): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     #00  pc 0003a4e0  /system/lib/libssl.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     #01  pc 0000849a  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     #02  pc 00047042  /system/lib/libssl.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     #03  pc 000201a3  /system/lib/libssl.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     #04  pc 0001ec57  /system/lib/libssl.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     #05  pc 000392bd  /system/lib/libssl.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     #06  pc 00015c39  /system/lib/libssl.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     #07  pc 0003bc52  /system/lib/libssl.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     #08  pc 00016b55  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     #09  pc 00083335  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     #10  pc 0006c48f  <unknown>
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     #11  pc 000e06dc  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     #12  pc 00237c79  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     #13  pc 00012a53  <unknown>
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     #14  pc 00098c80  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     #15  pc 000948c1  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     #16  pc 001144ae  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     #17  pc 00114877  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     #18  pc 000f24b2  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     #19  pc 0001c092  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     #20  pc 0004b805  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     #21  pc 000f20ff  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     #22  pc ffffffff  <unknown>
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     #23  pc 000048df  <unknown>
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     #24  pc 00003432  <unknown>
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     #25  pc 000038cf  <unknown>
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     #26  pc 000b4dff  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     #27  pc 00012f2f  /system/lib/libutils.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     #28  pc 000b952f  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     #29  pc 000b956f  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     #30  pc ffffffff  <unknown>
I/DEBUG   ( 1886): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1886): stack:
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d6e0  401217e0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d6e4  5f4aa486  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d6e8  413a8e74  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d6ec  412c1b37  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d6f0  00000006  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d6f4  00000002  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d6f8  4135e8e2  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d6fc  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d700  69655518  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d704  40039000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d708  6896d738  [stack:15518]
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d70c  412fe102  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d710  6a1fff80  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d714  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d718  4127f509  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d71c  41767478  /system/lib/libssl.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     #00  6896d720  685102e0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d724  685102d8  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d728  6896d798  [stack:15518]
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d72c  41766818  /system/lib/libssl.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d730  6953404d  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d734  41785a58  /system/lib/libssl.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d738  6953404d  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d73c  00000001  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d740  41785a58  /system/lib/libssl.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d744  6953404e  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d748  00000008  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d74c  412bce94  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d750  68693480  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d754  40039000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d758  00000190  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d75c  686940c0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          ........  ........
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     #01  6896d770  6896d7f8  [stack:15518]
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d774  6896d7f7  [stack:15518]
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d778  6953404d  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d77c  00000012  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d780  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d784  ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d788  68510318  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d78c  685102e0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d790  685102e0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d794  413a8e74  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d798  6896d7c8  [stack:15518]
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d79c  41785a58  /system/lib/libssl.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d7a0  686940c0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d7a4  00000012  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d7a8  6896d818  [stack:15518]
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d7ac  41774043  /system/lib/libssl.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):     #02  6896d7b0  686940c0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d7b4  6896d7f8  [stack:15518]
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d7b8  6896d7f7  [stack:15518]
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d7bc  6953404d  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d7c0  00000012  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d7c4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d7c8  6896d818  [stack:15518]
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d7cc  41752d80  /system/lib/libssl.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d7d0  00000001  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d7d4  00000001  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d7d8  6953405f  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d7dc  6953405b  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d7e0  69534049  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d7e4  6953404d  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d7e8  6953405f  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          6896d7ec  00000012  
I/DEBUG   ( 1886):          ........  ........
I/DEBUG   ( 1886): !@dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_native -m 15411
I/BootReceiver( 2344): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_00 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
I/dumpstate(15522): begin
D/dalvikvm( 2344): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 454K, 12% free 23948K/27116K, paused 119ms, total 119ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 2344): Grow heap (frag case) to 24.105MB for 131088-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm( 2344): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8K, 12% free 24067K/27248K, paused 96ms, total 97ms
D/dalvikvm( 2344): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 10K, 12% free 24074K/27248K, paused 97ms, total 98ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 2344): Grow heap (frag case) to 24.228MB for 131088-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm( 2344): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 12% free 24201K/27380K, paused 121ms, total 121ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 2344): Grow heap (frag case) to 24.415MB for 196628-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm( 2344): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 128K, 13% free 24265K/27576K, paused 78ms, total 78ms
D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController( 2542): refreshSignalCluster - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController( 2542): refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false
D/STATUSBAR-IconMerger( 2542): checkOverflow(588), More:false, Req:false Child:4
I/SurfaceFlinger( 1888): Device Built-in Screen -> ls 0 
E/android.os.Debug( 2344): !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
D/dalvikvm( 2344): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 14K, 12% free 24285K/27576K, paused 112ms, total 112ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 2344): Grow heap (frag case) to 24.434MB for 131116-byte allocation
I/dumpstate(15528): begin
I/dumpstate(15528): dumpstate is still running
D/dalvikvm( 2344): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 200K, 13% free 24213K/27708K, paused 109ms, total 109ms
D/dalvikvm( 2344): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 235K, 13% free 24189K/27708K, paused 103ms, total 103ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 2344): Grow heap (frag case) to 24.484MB for 281896-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm( 2344): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 13% free 24464K/27984K, paused 77ms, total 77ms
D/PointerIcon( 2344): setMouseIconStyle1 pointerType: 1001iconType:101 flag:0
D/PointerIcon( 2344): setMouseCustomIcon IconType is same.101
D/STATUSBAR-StatusBarManagerService( 2344): manageDisableList what=0x0 pkg=WindowManager.LayoutParams
D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor( 2542): sendKeyguardVisibilityChanged(true)
I/KeyguardUpdateMonitor( 2542): visibility is same
D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor( 2542): sendKeyguardVisibilityChanged(true)
I/KeyguardUpdateMonitor( 2542): visibility is same
I/BootReceiver( 2344): Notify a SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE FilePath:tombstone_00
W/ContextImpl( 2344): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1501 android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast:377 android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast:377 com.android.server.BootReceiver$2.onEvent:333 android.os.FileObserver$ObserverThread.onEvent:125 
E/IMGSRV  ( 1888): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 52
D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor( 2542): sendKeyguardVisibilityChanged(true)
I/KeyguardUpdateMonitor( 2542): visibility is same
D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor( 2542): sendKeyguardVisibilityChanged(true)
E/IMGSRV  ( 1888): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 54
I/KeyguardUpdateMonitor( 2542): visibility is same
D/dalvikvm( 2344): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 924K, 13% free 24365K/27984K, paused 84ms, total 84ms
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344): Build: samsung/santos10wifiue/santos10wifi:4.4.2/KOT49H/P5210UEU0CNK1:user/release-keys
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344): Hardware: clovertrail
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344): Revision: 0
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344): Bootloader: P5210UEU0CNH2
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344): Radio: unknown
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344): Kernel: Linux version 3.4.34-2435918 (dpi@SWDD5910) (gcc version 4.6 20120106 (prerelease) (GCC) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Nov 4 17:00:11 KST 2014
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344): 
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/santos10wifiue/santos10wifi:4.4.2/KOT49H/P5210UEU0CNK1:user/release-keys'
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344): Revision: '0'
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344): pid: 15411, tid: 15518, name: IntentService[E  >>> com.nellymoser.android.vosl <<<
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     eax ffffffff  ebx 00000000  ecx 00000008  edx 686940c0
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     esi 00000000  edi 00000008
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000000  xss 0000007b
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     eip 417674e0  ebp 6896d768  esp 6896d720  flags 00210246
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344): 
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344): backtrace:
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     #00  pc 0003a4e0  /system/lib/libssl.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     #01  pc 0000849a  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     #02  pc 00047042  /system/lib/libssl.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     #03  pc 000201a3  /system/lib/libssl.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     #04  pc 0001ec57  /system/lib/libssl.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     #05  pc 000392bd  /system/lib/libssl.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     #06  pc 00015c39  /system/lib/libssl.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     #07  pc 0003bc52  /system/lib/libssl.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     #08  pc 00016b55  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     #09  pc 00083335  /system/lib/libdvm.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     #10  pc 0006c48f  <unknown>
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     #11  pc 000e06dc  /system/lib/libdvm.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     #12  pc 00237c79  /system/lib/libdvm.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     #13  pc 00012a53  <unknown>
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     #14  pc 00098c80  /system/lib/libdvm.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     #15  pc 000948c1  /system/lib/libdvm.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     #16  pc 001144ae  /system/lib/libdvm.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     #17  pc 00114877  /system/lib/libdvm.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     #18  pc 000f24b2  /system/lib/libdvm.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     #19  pc 0001c092  /system/lib/libc.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     #20  pc 0004b805  /system/lib/libc.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     #21  pc 000f20ff  /system/lib/libdvm.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     #22  pc ffffffff  <unknown>
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     #23  pc 000048df  <unknown>
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     #24  pc 00003432  <unknown>
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     #25  pc 000038cf  <unknown>
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     #26  pc 000b4dff  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     #27  pc 00012f2f  /system/lib/libutils.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     #28  pc 000b952f  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     #29  pc 000b956f  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     #30  pc ffffffff  <unknown>
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344): 
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344): stack:
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d6e0  401217e0  
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d6e4  5f4aa486  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d6e8  413a8e74  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d6ec  412c1b37  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d6f0  00000006  
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d6f4  00000002  
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d6f8  4135e8e2  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d6fc  00000000  
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d700  69655518  
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d704  40039000  
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d708  6896d738  [stack:15518]
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d70c  412fe102  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d710  6a1fff80  
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d714  00000000  
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d718  4127f509  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d71c  41767478  /system/lib/libssl.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     #00  6896d720  685102e0  
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d724  685102d8  
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d728  6896d798  [stack:15518]
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d72c  41766818  /system/lib/libssl.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d730  6953404d  
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d734  41785a58  /system/lib/libssl.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d738  6953404d  
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d73c  00000001  
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d740  41785a58  /system/lib/libssl.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d744  6953404e  
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d748  00000008  
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d74c  412bce94  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d750  68693480  
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d754  40039000  
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d758  00000190  
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d75c  686940c0  
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          ........  ........
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):     #01  6896d770  6896d7f8  [stack:15518]
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d774  6896d7f7  [stack:15518]
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d778  6953404d  
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d77c  00000012  
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d780  00000000  
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d784  ffffffff  
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d788  68510318  
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d78c  685102e0  
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d790  685102e0  
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d794  413a8e74  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d798  6896d7c8  [stack:15518]
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d79c  41785a58  /system/lib/libssl.so
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d7a0  686940c0  
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d7a4  00000012  
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d7a8  6896d818  [stack:15518]
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344):          6896d7ac  41774043  /system
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344): processName:com.nellymoser.android.vosl
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2344): broadcastEvent : com.nellymoser.android.vosl SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE
W/ContextImpl( 2344): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1515 com.android.server.analytics.data.collection.application.CrashAnrDetector.broadcastEvent:296 com.android.server.analytics.data.collection.application.CrashAnrDetector.processDropBoxEntry:254 com.android.server.analytics.data.collection.application.CrashAnrDetector.access$100:60 com.android.server.analytics.data.collection.application.CrashAnrDetector$1.onReceive:102 
I/SurfaceFlinger( 1888): Device Built-in Screen -> ls 0
```

**UPDATE:**
It turned out that the problem was caused by an older version of okhttp library. See here: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/184#issuecomment-18772733

After migrating to the latest okhttp library, the problem was gone.

Comment: Could we see some code? Can you set a break point and debug to the line that causes the crash?

Comment: Problem is that I don't know where it crashed. The UI piece works fine, something in the background caused it to crash. So it crashed randomly, and only crashes about 5% of the time when I tested it.

Comment: Would you happen to be using Bluetooth?

Comment: @HuaHou, Please ignore it. Might be are you using genymotion.

Comment: I am using neither bluetooth nor genymotion. The crash occurred on Samsung galaxy tab pro 10.1 device (OS 4.4.2). I do use Crashlytics and UrbanAirship. Out of 100 push messages I tested yesterday, it crashed about 5 to 10 times.

Comment: This also looks like an IntentService started by GCM.  How many bytes are you sending in the push notification?  Intent extras are limited in size.

Comment: The push message has about less than 80 characters. I sent exactly the same message for about 100 times, and it only crashed 5 to 10 times out of these 100.

Comment: Looks like there is a segmentation error in SSL library. Are you doing any decryption or so using SSL? Also try testing in other devices.